# Unable to prevent gridview from refreshing when dropdownlist is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a gridview filled with data under the page_load. This gridview is sortable by alphabet and has a paging ability. However, after selecting a dropdownlist value, the sorted information of my gridview reset to the default page_load data.

I added update panel and trigger but it still doesn't work. I searched all of the SO thread and all advises the trigger and the update panel. I also enable the auto post back in the dropdownlist. The ID of the ddl is also correct.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>

      **GridView**      

    *dropdownlist category*
    *search textbox*
    *search button*


</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers> 
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCategory" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
</Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

How do i exactly prevent the selection of the ddl value from making my sorted ddl's value from resetting to the default data found in page_load.

This is how i bind my gridview in the page_load

```
Session["gridview"] = DataBindByDataSet();

GVPolice.DataSource = Session["gridview"];
GVPolice.DataBind();
```

This is the datatable method

```
private DataTable DataBindByDataSet()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                conn.Open();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(*sql command*);
                da.Fill(ds);

                conn.Close();

                 return ds.Tables[0];               

   }
```

Comment: how and where are you binding gridview? Put that code also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the binding code in below `if` condition on `Page_Load()` method, so that it will not bind when there is postback.

```
//not post back i.e. first time load
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Session["gridview"] = DataBindByDataSet();

    GVPolice.DataSource = Session["gridview"];
    GVPolice.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that since you are using the Session for Data handling, so just update this session in your sorting function. So that after every sort the session has the latest sorted dataset.

in your sorting function

```
Session["gridview"] = Whatever sorted dataset you get.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just disable the auto postback & prevent it from refreshing.